# emacs does not uses fonts from /usr/share/fonts

Tags: emacs, fonts

Can't win in emacs font battle under Debian Linux+fluxbox.

Should be mentioned that I have absolutely no expirience in fontconfig, so mb I am missing something obvious.

I am trying to use some system fonts from /usr/share/fonts like DejaVu under emacs but no luck.

I tried:

1.
Mentioned on many resources commands like

```
(set-default-font "DejaVu Sans Mono-12")
```

returns "Font not available" for almost any fontname I tried.

2.

```
Shift+Mouse-Left-Click->Change Text Font ->
```

gives very little list of available fonts with two or three and different sizes.

3.
I tried:

```
ln -s /usr/share/fonts ~/.fonts
```

and nothing

4.
tried using xset method for(found such method on archlinux wiki and blindly tested):

```
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
sudo mkfontdir
xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
xset fp rehash
```

nothing

5.
I even straced emacs for any acces to directories with font name:

```
2>&1 strace -f emacs-24.3.1 > ./t.txt
```

but

```
grep -i font ./t.txt
```

gives only:

```
[pid 18809] writev(3, [{"b\1\6\0\17\0\1\0", 8}, {"XFree86-Bigfont", 15}, {"\0", 1}], 3) = 24
```

and nothing about directories like ~/.fonts or /usr/share/fonts

At the same time:

```
% fc-list|grep -c deja  
42
```

How does it work?:( Mb i dont understand some main idea?

UPDATE: 
I've used opensoop -v to monitor what path uses emacs  on my laptop (under os x) to get fonts but this has nothing with linux paths ofc:(

Can someone under the linux trace emacs for opening fonts to give a hint what paths I should configure.

```
2>&1 strace -f  emacs |grep -i font
```

will be enough i think

Comment: Where are you getting your Emacs? What version is it? (Find out from the Emacs about screen, which you can reach via `C-h C-a` -- that means "press Control-H, then Control-A", and is an example of the Emacs notation for keystrokes, familiarity with which is necessary to use Emacs fluently.) The current Emacs version is 24.3; anything older than 23.x is going to miss a considerable number of useful features. Also, as with e.g. Perl, vendors sometimes do stupid things when they package Emacs for distribution, so you may want to consider building your own.

Comment: I tried on both version: one coming from debian

    % emacs --version
    GNU Emacs 23.4.1

and fresh build of 
% ./emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.3.1
 Downloaded from off site.
Seems it is something with system or X configuration as a whole. But all other applications I use see much more fonts, to be honest I'v never met such situation an thus has no expirience in fonts-battle:(

Comment: Did you try to set the face attributes directly? I.e. `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "DejaVu Sans Mono" :height 120)` instead of `set-default-font`? By the way, `set-default-font` is obsolete, use `set-frame-font`.

Comment: using set-face changes only font size but not the font itself :( returns nil. 
set-frame-font gives "font not found" message:( I think the absence of font-directories acces in strace output states that emacs simly does not search any font-config files there...
I am definetely missing some x configuration but can't find what exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Was my fault.

I'v checked with ldd command and saw that there was no dependecny from libfreetype.

And only configuration like:

```
./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk
```

added freetype library dependency to binary. So from now it is ok.

One more thing to notice about "default system emacs" errors. Emacs binary i thought was the system one,was also custom builded long time ago (also without freetype support), and according to my paths configurations this custom one was executed when I simply typed "emacs" without path specification.

I am very shame, sorry for such misconfiguration.
To be honest its very strange that no default freetype support is configured.

Comment: Use of freetype and GTK is default in 24.3.  Are you building an older version?

Comment: @JSON As mentioned above I built 24.3. Resulting makefile depends on packages you have at the moment of configure. No gtk dev libs?

You will get `./configure`:  
`Does Emacs use -lfreetype? no`  

After installing `./configure` gives:
    `Does Emacs use -lfreetype? yes`

But with `./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk` key, configure will produce error in case of gtk-dev libs absence. Without that key it simply disables functional.